# WebAuthn isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable

Tags: javascript, authentication, webauthn, fido

When I use the above on Chrome 87 on my Windows PC I get "true"

window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()
.then(x=>{alert('x is '+x);console.log(x)})

Yet when I run the example referred to in the docs https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/ and click the ISUVPAA button and set a break point at line 421 in webauth.js in another tab and step through it returns "false".

I must be doing something silly but was wondering how you could get "false" when surely access to any numeric keypad (to enter a PIN) would result in a positive result?

Answer (score 2):

I worked out that you receive a "false" response if you have the WebAuthn DevTools enabled. IOW have ticked the "Enable virtual authenticator environment" box. Strange?

Looks like it's down to the "Supports User Verification" tick box on the Virtual Authenticator. Looks like I need a lot more reading to get a PIN verification happening.

Comment: As you have discovered, if you have the virtual authenticator environment enabled, IsUVPAA will return `true` only if you have a platform, user verification enabled authenticator added. This is so you can test your page with IsUVPAA both returning `true` and `false`. If you want to try the "real" windows hello implementation, just disable the virtual authenticator environment. Hope this helps!